# Bounty etiquette: Answering my own question with someone else's bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty, etiquette

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567437/incorrect-date-formatting-when-vb-program-opened-via-c-sharp) last week and had great discussion in the comments while clarifying details. Unfortunately, there were no correct answers right away. One of the commenters posted a +100 bounty to the question, which excited me - maybe I'd get an answer faster!

This evening I discovered a fix for the problem myself. I've added my answer, but the "bounty" concept is new to me and I feel icky accepting someone else's points for answering my own question or having those points just go to waste. I also feel icky leaving the question unanswered in case there's someone else struggling with a similar situation!

I've read through the bounty FAQ and searched similar questions, but couldn't find good guidance for this: should I wait before accepting my own answer, in case a better & more-detailed explanation comes through? Or am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no issue with self-answering your own question on which someone else has put a bounty on. The purpose of a bounty is to promote answers from users other than the bounty starter; if you're not the bounty starter, that includes you.

The [bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on Meta Stack Exchange specifically addresses this case:

> #### If I offer a bounty on someone else's question, can I award the bounty to their answer?
>
> Yes, a bounty can be awarded to any answer except one posted by the person offering the bounty.
>
> This means that if you offer a bounty on someone else's question, and the original poster of that question posts a self-answer, you can award the bounty to their answer.

Keep in mind that *the bounty starter*, not you, get to choose which answer to award the bounty to, so if they find your answer good enough, they just might choose your answer. That's a reward for contributing to the repository of knowledge that is Stack Overflow.

So, go ahead and post your answer; don't feel too qualmish about it.

Comment: And if the bounty starter doesn't choose, in some cases the system chooses. That is where OP could have some limited influence.

Comment: Luuklag's note there was my concern, but it doesn't seem like that's a huge deal - ultimately, the bounty starter is _making a choice_ by _choosing no one_. :) Thank you!

Comment: @Luuklag If someone else starts the bounty, the author has *no* influence over who gets the bounty; the rule that the accepted answer gets it only applies if the author starts it. However, it *can* affect the rep they get, as if the answer that the system would otherwise choose happens to be accepted, it gets the full bounty instead of half.

Comment: @gparyani that was what I was referring to.